# How long does this temporary object returning another temporary object live?

Tags: c++, lifetime, callstack

Consider the following code example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct outer {

    struct ret {
        outer &a;
        ret(outer &a) : a(a) { }
        template <typename T>
        friend ret &operator<<(ret &r, const T &obj)
        {
            std::cout << "wrote: " << obj << std::endl;
            return r;
        }
        template <typename T>
        friend ret &&operator<<(ret &&r, const T &obj)
        {
            std::cout << "wrote: " << obj << std::endl;
            return std::move(r);
        }
        ~ret() { std::cout << "ret destroyed" << std::endl; }
    };

    template <typename T>
    ret operator<<(const T &obj)
    {
        std::cout << "starting." << std::endl;
        return ret(*this) << obj;
    }
    ~outer() { std::cout << "outer destroyed" << std::endl; }
};
```

It consists of two nested structs, the outer of which returns an instance of the inner for the `operator<<`, which in turn has an operator overload returning an (rvalue) reference to the same object.
Note how the returned object of the inner class `ret` contains a reference to the outer object; when constructed `*this` is passed as constructor argument.

One possible way to use this would be like this:

```
int main()
{
    outer b;
    b << 1 << 2 << 3;
    b << "abc";
}
```

This will work as I would expect and print

> starting. 
>   wrote: 1 
>   ret destroyed  // here control returns from `outer::operator<<` 
>   wrote: 2 
>   wrote: 3 
>   ret destroyed 
>   starting. 
>   wrote: abc 
>   ret destroyed 
>   ret destroyed 
>   outer destroyed

Another way would be

```
int main()
{
    outer() << 1 << 2 << 3;
}
```

Which also prints the expected output

> starting. 
>   wrote: 1 
>   ret destroyed 
>   wrote: 2 
>   wrote: 3 
>   ret destroyed 
>   outer destroyed

However, I wonder why the temporary object of type `outer` is destroyed at the end of the program.

Is it possible in this example, that this temporary object created by `outer()` is destroyed before the completion of the line and thus leaving the created `ret` object with a dangling reference to an `outer` object?

I have prepared an example on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5eQXDT).

### Update

To answer @user4581301 's concern, the `outer` object is indeed destroyed directly after the `;` and not at the end of `main`.

Comment: Well elaborated question. Unfortunately, needed a bit more research and example minimisation.

Comment: Pop a `std::cout << "Exiting"<< std::endl;` after `outer() << 1 << 2 << 3;` to see if the temporary `outer` really is going out of scope at the end of `main`. Right now it  could be going out of scope at the end of the line as expected and there is no good way to tell the end of the line from the end of `main`.